# Kivy coordinate system

Tags: python, kivy

I am having trouble to understand the `Kivy` coordinate system. 
At the moment I have an Image inside a `Scatter` widget that can be scaled and translated.

From what I understood (and please correct me if I am wrong) when we translate the Scatter only the position of the Scatter changes, the position of the image is relative to the Scatter so it will appear that the image position changes as well but its relative position will remain the same. When we scale the Scatter I am not quite sure of what happens I guess it only transforms the way it renders its children.

Now I am trying to identify which pixel is clicked when we click on the Image. For that I did:

```
class ClickableImage(Image):
    def on_touch_down(self,touch):
        if self.collide_point(*touch.pos):
                print touch.pos
                return True
        else:
            return super(ClickableImage,self).on_touch_down(touch)
```

It seems that the `touch.pos` as always an offset, when I click the bottom left corner of the image I get the `touch.pos = (0,200)`. Maybe the `touch.pos` reference frame origin is not the image but its parent. So I printed instead `self.to_local(*touch.pos)`, same result. If I print instead `self.touch.pos-self.pos` it works! But now I don't understand the coordinates system because I thought that the local reference frame origin would be `self.pos` so `self.to_local(*touch.pos)` shoud be equal to `touch.pos-self.pos`.